# MapStruct Java: property to list

Tags: java, mapstruct

Shortly, I'd like to move this code inside a mapstruct mapper:

```java
List<Provincia> provincies = resultSetType.getResults().getResult().stream()
    .map(resultType -> ResultTypeToProvinciaMapper.INSTANCE.resultTypeToProvincia(resultType))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'd like to have:

```java
List<Provincia> provinces = ResultTypeToProvinciaMapper.INSTANCE.getList(resultSet);
```

#### Details

My source class:

```java
public class ResultSetType {

    protected SearchRequestType request;
    protected Results results;
    protected Long resultCount;
    protected Long totalCount;
    protected Long startIndex;
    protected Long pageSize;
    protected ResultSetType.Errors errors;

    // getters & setters

}
```

where `Results` is:

```java
public static class Results {

    protected List<ResultType> result;

    // geters & setters

}
```

And `ResultType`:

```java
public class ResultType {

    protected String id;
    protected String description;

    // getters & setters

}
```

My `Service` class is getting a `ResultSetType` object from my `Repository`:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ServeiTerritorialServiceImpl implements ServeiTerritorialService {

    private final ServeiTerritorialClientRepository serveiTerritorialClientRepository;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void getPaisos() {
        ResultSetType resultSetType = this.serveiTerritorialClientRepository.getOid("2.16.724.4.400");

        // here I need to map resultSetType to a List<Provincia>...
    }

}
```

I need to map `resultSetType` to `List<Provincia>`.

So, I need to map `resultSetType.results.result` to `List<Provincia>`.

First of all, I've created a `mapper` in order to map `ResultType` to `Provincia`:

```java
@Mapper
public interface ResultTypeToProvinciaMapper {
    
    ResultTypeToProvinciaMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ResultTypeToProvinciaMapper.class);
    
    @Mapping(source = "id", target = "code")
    @Mapping(source = "description", target = "name")
    Provincia resultTypeToProvincia(ResultType resultType);

}
```

However, I can't quite figure out how to travel from `resultSetType.results.result` to `List<Provincia>`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MapStruct you can define mapping between different iterable. However, you can map from a nested listed into a top level list in a method (You can if it is wrapped though).

In any case for this I would suggest doing the following:

```
@Mapper
public interface ResultTypeToProvinciaMapper {
    
    ResultTypeToProvinciaMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ResultTypeToProvinciaMapper.class);
    

    default List<Provincia> resultSetToListOfProvincia(ResultSetType resultSetType) {
        if (resultSetType == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Results results = resultSetType.getResults();

        if (results == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return resultTypesToProvincias(results.getResult());
    }


    List<Provincia> resultTypesToProvincias(List<ResultType> resultTypes);

    @Mapping(source = "id", target = "code")
    @Mapping(source = "description", target = "name")
    Provincia resultTypeToProvincia(ResultType resultType);

}
```